# unable to execute select.php on Alarm OnReceive method in android code

Tags: java, php, android

I have MainActivity.java in android application

in that I have `setRepeatingAlarm()` which executes after every `120sec` and executes select.php which check for name available in table or not.

```
public void setRepeatingAlarm() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TimeAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+120000,
    (120000), pendingIntent);
}
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class TimeAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //get select query data
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.myweb.com/select.php");

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();   
            if(is != null) {
                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

                 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                 Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                    .setTicker("mytestapp")

                                    .setContentTitle("mytestapp")
                                    .setContentText("Please check new update!")
                                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                                    //At most three action buttons can be added
                                    .setAutoCancel(true).build();
                int notifyID =0;
                notificationManager.notify(notifyID, noti);
            }

            is.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

> but i'm unable to execute `HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);` goes into catch block . not getting any error details :(

select.php gives output like `{"name":"mynametest"}` OR `null`

suggest me what is wrong here

Comment: Check logcat. It is likely you are getting `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. The reason is the `onReceive(...)` method of a `BroadcastReceiver` runs on the main (UI) thread and you're not allowed to run network operations on that. I'd recommend you use an `IntentService` to perform the what you want to do and simply start that in the `onReceive` method of the `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: great it is giving error `"Too much work in main thread"`
can you help me and show how to use `IntentService` in `onReceive` in my above code ... i'm very new to android.  thanks a lot

Comment: OK, give me a few minutes and I'll add an answer with some basic code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from my comment on your question - you can move your network code into an `IntentService` and simply start that from your `BroadcastReceiver`. All of the work in an `IntentService` is handled by a worker thread running the `onHandleIntent(...)` method so it's safe to do network tasks in there.

The `IntentService`:

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {

    // You must have a parameter-less ctor for an IntentService
    public MyIntentService() {
        super("MyIntentService");
    }

    public MyIntentService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        // This method is run on a separate worker thread so it's
        // safe to put all of your network code here

    }
}
```

Copy everything you currently have in the `BroadcastReceiver` `onReceive(...)` method into the `onHandleIntent(...)` method of your `IntentService` and replace it with code to start the service as follows...

```
public class TimeAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MyIntentService.class);
        context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `startService(i)` method where it is?  :/
it is giving me error said `The method startService(Intent) is undefined for the type TimeAlarm Create method`

Comment: @ashish : Sorry - that probably should be `context.startService(i)`

Comment: protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) `i need to give Context also right as i'm using it in further code`
but it makes class as abstract like this `
public abstract class MyIntentService extends IntentService `

Comment: @ashish : In `onHandleIntent(...)` you can use `getApplicationContext()` to get a valid `Context`.

Comment: @ashish : Actually, thinking about it, `IntentService` indirectly extends `Context` so you can simply use `this` to get a valid `Context` when you need one.

Comment: okies thanks but after toogle brakpoint comes here `onReceive` it is unable to go to  `class MyIntentService` `onHandleIntent` :( 
i did everything !

Comment: @ashish : Have you added the service to the AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: sorry i forgot let me check all :)